# Powershell: using -replace with regular expression

Tags: regex, string, powershell, replace

How can I use a regular expression to replace any text between quotes for a `-replace` statement?  I can get it to work with static text, but it could be virtually any text.

Example:

```
$filecontent -replace 'AssemblyCopyright("text")', 'AssemblyCopyright("Copyright © 2016 myCompany")' | Out-File $file
```

given the `AssemblyCopyright("text")` could actually be anything including blank

```
AssemblyCopyright("")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like this

```
... -replace 'AssemblyCopyright\("[^"]*"\)', 'AssemblyCopyright("Copyright © 2016 myCompany")'
```

Please note however, that this will assume that the text within the quotes does not contain another quote.

---

Example due to comment

[image: GIF example]

Comment: That's a lot closer that I have gotten.  The only problem is there's an A character in front of the copyright.  I think regex or powershell does NOT like the copyright symbol

Comment: I think that is an encoding issue on your side - I did a quick test within PoSh ISE with no issues - please see the GIF

Comment: I am looking into it now.  I think you have certainly solved it.  Just needs some polish! :D  Thank you! :D